# Footnotes for author affiliations and corresponding author not working properly

Tags: titles, author

I'm trying to add footnotes to author names according to their role. There are two people who are co-first author and I'd like to use the superscripted $1$ to express that. I'd also like to use the asterisk symbol to mark my advisor as the corresponding author.

Right now, I've tried using the `\author{Author 1} \thanks{Something}` but the `thanks` keeps returning an asterisk, and so I tried using `\footnote` but strangely enough that also returns an asterisk (as opposed to the presumed default numbering that I observed in most of the other resources).

The code that I have looks something like:

```
\title{\titlefont{Title of the paper.}}

\author{
Author 1\thanks{Thanks 1} \and Author 2$^{\text{1}}$ \and Author 3 \and Author 4* \footnote{Corresponding author}\\
School name\\
\{author1, author2, author3, author4\}@school.edu}
```

This results in `Author 1` having a small asterisk next to their name and `Author 4` having both a large asterisk and a dagger next to their name, with `Thanks 1` as a footnote at the bottom next to a small asterisk.

What I'm looking for is to have both `1` next to `Author 1` and `Author 2` and a large asterisk next to `Author 4`, with footnotes in the form of:

```
1 Equally contributed.
* Corresponding author.
```

Would anybody be able to give some pointers? Thanks.

Comment: What document class are you using?  (Different document classes treat these things differently, so it isn't possible to answer this question without more information.)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. I had a hunch but I'm not that familiar with LaTeX. After checking I've observed that I'm using the `article` document class.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am trying to solve a similar problem described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604368/affiliations-and-corresponding-author-comments-as-footnotes-on-latex-article).